# How to delete Gmail associated with friend's account

Tags: gmail, google-account

I am facing a problem in GMail. I accessed my GMail on my friend's laptop. At that time he added my account details to his account. After this, he is sending mails to everybody from his account, but it is showing my name and his email id.

When he is chatting in GMail from his account, it is showing my name. Whenever he is changing his profile picture my photo also changes automatically.

I requested him to delete my account from his account details, but he is not doing so.

How can I correct this?

Answer (score 2):

Not sure how one could "add account details" to another account. It sounds as though your friend is using your account, because you didn't log out from your Gmail account at his computer.

Provided you can still login to your account from your own computer, you can execute a "remote logout" (for details, see [the Gmail blog](http://gmailblog.blogspot.no/2008/07/remote-sign-out-and-info-to-help-you.html)):

1. Scroll to the bottom of your inbox, locate the *Last account activity* information (to the far right), and click *Details*: [image: Last account activity text]
2. Click *Sign out all other sessions*: [image: Screenshot of Activity on this account]

Your account is no longer logged in at your friend's computer. If I were you, I'd also change my Gmail password, in case your friend logged it/watched you enter it.

Answer (score 1):

Another possibility is that you (ie your account) gave him permission to send emails on your behalf, which you need to revoke.

(It's unlikely to be only this, if he is able to change your profile picture too, but this is worth checking too.)

**How to control who can send emails on your behalf:**

Log into gmail.com

Choose Settings from the Options gear-wheel  (top right corner).

Choose the Accounts and Imports tab.

Now, there will be a list beside Send Mail As.

Beside every entry on this list, there are options to:

- Make it the sending default for your account
- Edit the sending information (mainly the display name)
- Delete its rights to send on your behalf.

If your friend's own email address is listed here, you should use the delete option.

[image: example gmail settings screen]